# PyTorch: Multi GPU error: RuntimeError: binary_op(): expected both inputs to be on same device, but input a is on cuda:0 and input b is on cuda:7

Tags: gpu, pytorch, multi-gpu

When I use multiple GPUs
and also when I use .cuda() for the tensors
in the middle of training, I got following error

```
RuntimeError: binary_op(): expected both inputs to be on same device, 
but input a is on cuda:0 and input b is on cuda:7
```

which means following `R2` is on cuda:7 (not sure R2 in on cuda:0 or cuda:7) and
`R1` is on cuda:0
so, operation is impossible because they’re on difference GPU

```
R2=torch.where(R2<1e-4,torch.Tensor([1e-4]).squeeze().cuda(),R2)
div_R1_R2=torch.div(R1,R2)
```

I get exactly same error in the following code
complaining `O_img_tc` and `R_gt_img_tc` can’t be calculated
because they’re on different GPU

```
R_gt_img_tc=torch.where(
  torch.abs(R_gt_img_tc)<1e-4,
  torch.Tensor([1e-4]).squeeze().cuda(),R_gt_img_tc)
sha=torch.clamp(torch.div(O_img_tc,R_gt_img_tc),0.0,1.3)[:,0,:,:].unsqueeze(1)
```

How to solve this, and what am I doing wrong?

---

What I've tried:
- Use horovod: got same error.
- Check the GPU number by using `dense_O_img_tc.get_device()` and `dense_S_gt_img_tc.get_device()`
When they were like `dense_O_img_tc.get_device()` returned `0`, `dense_S_gt_img_tc.get_device()` returned `7`

And I tried this

```
same_cuda=torch.device('cuda:'+str(dense_O_img_tc.get_device()))
dense_S_gt_img_tc=torch.where(
  torch.abs(dense_S_gt_img_tc)<1e-4,
  # Note here that I'm using cuda(same_cuda)
  torch.Tensor([1e-4]).squeeze().cuda(same_cuda),dense_S_gt_img_tc)

ref=torch.div(dense_O_img_tc,dense_S_gt_img_tc)
```

That actually could resolved "different GPU issue"
but only GPU:0 was used, resulting in full of GPU:0 error.

- So, I tried to move `dense_O_img_tc` which is on the GPU:0 towards GPU:7 (or anywhere dense_S_gt_img_tc is on by using dense_S_gt_img_tc.get_device()), I might have got following illegal memory access error

```
RuntimeError: cuda runtime error (77) : an illegal memory access was encountered at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1544199946412/work/aten/src/THC/generic/THCTensorMath.cu:238
```

Comment: If someone is having difficulty with multiple GPUs on PyTorch, this is the solution at least for my case, discuss.pytorch.org/t/difference-device-error-when-i-use-multiple-gpus-with-creating-new-cuda-tensor/41676